# Print from Word to plotter at largest page size

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing, printer, microsoft-word-2013

I can't get Word to print an entire large page (almost A2) despite the fact that my plotter can print anything up to A0 and never has a problem. I get that Word only can do to 55cm and that is limited when setting the page size so I just used 55cm as one dimension. The other is 42cm.

But the print preview shows only part of the page will print because the print limits are down to A4. Wtf?

I have put a lot into this poster and can't redo it somewhere else as I actually have a lot of work to do.

Comment: Yes, Word is limited to 55 mm. Try using a scale factor (200%)  in the driver but I don't know if that will position the print correctly on the paper. It should be under the Layout tab in Printer Properties when you print

Comment: No, it's cropping the page to A4. It's not the scale that's the problem but how much actually prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went back to it and realised that the printer page size was still A2 so it was not able to properly send the print despite having the page size in Word set up correctly. I still have some of it cut off but that may  be the printer not Word as Word shows that it will all be printed.